# I am receiving a message saying I have duplicate sources but I can't seem to find a duplicate of the line described, any ideas?

Tags: 12.04, updates, duplicate-files

I receive this meassage when I run sudo apt-get update in the terminal:-
Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise/partner i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_partner_binary-i386_Packages)

So i ran the command gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list and checked the source to find there was no duplicate, not that I can see anyway.
Here is the source:-

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20120423)]/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted #Added by software-properties

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise restricted main multiverse  universe #Added by software-properties

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
```

I can see there are two lines of **deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner** but one has #deb-src at the beginning of it.  Hashed out no?

I'm quite new to linux OS and have little to none sourced editing skills so any help would be most appreciated.

Thank you:)